Unable to make CloudFront cache 503 errors (triggered from Lambda@Edge origin request)
I have a Lambda@Edge origin request that is in charge of access checking. The Lambda@Edge pass the response as-is when access is granted or return a specific 401 error page (not handled with custom CloudFront error pages).
If the Lambda@Edge throws (or times out), it will make CloudFront hit the 503 custom error page and that's cool. I want the 503 response for which the custom error page is being fetched to be cached for 5 minutes (in order to protect Lambda@Edge underlying infra in case of major problem).
I've configured a custom error page on 503:
# Service Unavailable
- ErrorCode: 503
  ResponseCode: 503
  ResponsePagePath: /errors/503.html
  ErrorCachingMinTTL: 300 # 5 minutes

And caching policies:
MinTTL: 7200 # 2 hours
MaxTTL: 7200 # 2 hours
DefaultTTL: 7200 # 2 hours

Those are the cache-control HTTP response headers (rewritten by a Lambda@Edge origin response):

200 -> public, max-age=31536000
401 -> public, max-age=10 (I tried both without and with , stale-if-error=0)
503 -> public, max-age=300

I've updated my  Lambda@Edge origin request that is in charge of access checking to throw voluntary errors on 50% of the time.
When the Lambda@Edge origin request throws, I get a 503 error as expected but when I refresh the page in the browser (with browser cache disabled) I see on CloudWatch that CloudFront doesn't hit the 503 error cache for 5 minutes but constantly tries to fetch the origin!
Why? Isn't 503 errors supposed to be cached for 5 minutes and during this time for this specific URL the origin should NOT be fetched by CloudFront.
Is it special because the error comes from Lambda@Edge origin request? (I have a dead simple S3 as origin). I've noticed that on error I have this HTTP response header:
X-Cache: LambdaExecutionError from cloudfront

This is driving me crazy :) any clue on how to cache 503 errors for 5 minutes in order to protect my  Lambda@Edge origin request from being overwhelmed?
See also: https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/1ct9ly4/

Just to confirm, are you saying that you've seen the 503 responses and they have a Cache-Control: public, max-age=300 header? (That is, you're not just assuming that based on your configuration?) If so, I agree with you that CloudFront should be caching the 503. Do note, though, that caching is optional. So if CloudFront has a policy of not caching 5xx errors and always checking with the origin, that would be perfectly compliant with the HTTP specification. Of course, they should document that if that's the case.
